# What is meant from KO in JMeter statistics table?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

When you generate jmeter [dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html), you get a table called statistics. It shows similar stats like one of the GIU views provide when you run JMeter in GUI mode.

There is a column called "KO" under "executions" section of the table.

[image: Jmeter statistics table on JMeter dashboard]

What does the "KO" stands for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, KO means "not OK" or "Failure". It is possible to [rename](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/26690) it if needed.

Comment: Thanks... Just curious, is this related to something coming from any language?

Comment: You can check this [discussion](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-the-French-use-KO-meaning-not-OK-Who-can-trace-how-it-started-and-how-it-got-widespread-apparently-only-in-France), where they blame Frenchmen, but, most likely, it is just the shortest way (used mainly in IT) how to write "not OK".

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer [here](https://octoperf.com/blog/2017/10/19/how-to-analyze-jmeter-results/).

KO: Total Number of samples failed to execute.

However I still don't know why it's called "KO"